# UI test to validate that clicking on the menu item in the toolbar updates the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am new to UI testing using Espresso. I want sample Test for checking that if I press menu item in toolbar it updates Recyclerview or not.

I have written till performing the click on toolbar menu but can't find how to check if Recyclerview is updated or not

```
    import org.junit.Rule;
    import org.junit.Test;

    import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

    import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
    import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
    import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
    import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
    import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

    public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;

    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
    mIdlingResource = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
    }

    @Test
    public void clickFilterBUtton_UpdatesRecyclerview() {

    int adapterSizeBeforeUpdate, adapterSizeAfterUpdate;

    adapterSizeBeforeUpdate = getRVcount();

    onView((withId(R.id.action_filter)))
            .perform(click());

    adapterSizeAfterUpdate= getRVcount();

    Assert.assertTrue(adapterSizeBeforeUpdate!=adapterSizeAfterUpdate);

    }

    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
        if (mIdlingResource != null) {
            Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
        }
    }

    private int getRVcount(){
        GridView gridView = (GridView) 
mActivityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tea_grid_view);
        return gridView.getAdapter().getCount();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check recyclerView adapter size before click and after click like below:

```
    import org.junit.Rule;
        import org.junit.Test;

        import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

        import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
        import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
        import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
        import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
        import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

        public class MainActivityTest {

        @Rule
        public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule =
                new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);


        @Test
        public void clickFilterBUtton_UpdatesRecyclerview() {

           int adapterSizeBeforeUpdate, adapterSizeAfterUpdate;
           adapterSizeBeforeUpdate= getRVcount();
           onView((withId(R.id.action_filter))).check(matches(withText("Show Favorites")));

           onView((withId(R.id.action_filter)))
                    .perform(click());
           adapterSizeAfterUpdate= getRVcount();
           Assert.assertEquals(adapterSizeBeforeUpdate, adapterSizeAfterUpdate);
        }



        private int getRVcount(){
           RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mActivityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_view);
           return recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
    }


}
```

Comment: That was accepted answer but I am stuck in error of loading. I have added IdlingResource but still it does not wait for loading and gives exception